# Enabling manual sorting for entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities, "Course" and "Person".

1) One or more Persons are responsible for a course

2) A course can contain of other courses.

Now I want to realize the ability to add a manual sort sequence for both, the responsible persons and the contained courses.

That means, it should be able to display the courses like this:

```
Course 1:
  Responsible Persons:
   1. Person A
   2. Person B
   3. Person C

Course 2:
  Responsible Persons:
   1. Person B
   2. Person A
   3. Person C
```

And this order can be declared when creating a Course. But there is nothing like a role-concept for different users, who are using the application. So to say, there will only be "one" user and nothing like a `User` class.

As you can see in the diagram below. I thought of two new classes called "SortableCourse" and "SortablePerson" which contain an additional ID for the sorting.

1) Is this a good approach?

2) I will use Java and Hibernate for the OR-Mapping:

2.1) Do I miss something, that could cause problems later on with the mapping / creation of the tables?

2.2) Could it be a problem, that Person has a List of Courses, but the Course has a list of SortablePersons? Because from the database-view I guess, it would be enough to have a table with Course IDs and SortablePerson IDs. Does anyone have experience how Hibernate will "translate" this?

Hope my idea got clear, thanks in advance for any hints!

[image: Course class diagram]

Comment: You are missing one important entity in your diagram: the user. When you try to model that you will notice, that the `consistsOf` attribute makes no sense.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail? The `consistsOf` attribute means, that a course can (but not has to) have one or more "sub-courses". Where should the user come in?

Comment: Did you mean to sort the courses and persons _per user_? That's what I guessed from _the ability for the user to add a manual sort sequence_. And in that case you would have to store the sequence per user.

Comment: Btw. I'm usually preach a _classes first_ approach. Usually a straight class design leads to a straight table design as well.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke I edited my post, hope that makes it a bit more clean. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a table layout or UML diagram lets look what JPA is able to do:

```
@Entity
public class Course {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Person> responsiblePersons;

    @OneToMany
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Course> consistsOf;
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsiblePerson")
    private List<Course> responsibleFor;
}
```

The important thing is the `List` with the `@OrderColumn` declaration which indicates that the mapping has a stable order.

This will create four tables:

```
COURSE
------
id, ...

PERSON
------
id, ...

COURSE_PERSON
------
course_id, responsiblePersons_id, responsiblePersons_order

COURSE_COURSE
------
course_id, consistsOf_id, consistsOf_order
```

So no need to invent some "wrapper" entities.

Comment: Where in the code do you tell to create the `responsiblePersons_order` and the `consistsOf_order`?

Comment: If you use a `List` interface without a `OrderBy` annotation the JPA framework will guess that you want to save the order. In difference to a `Set` or `Collection`.

Comment: I implemented it as you told above but no order column was created. Nevertheless I could add the behavior with @OrderColumn Annotation. But there are also two tables who get created COURSE_PERSON and PERSON_COURSE, what is right in the way that there exist two different orders. The ordering of the courses of a person and the ordering of persons of a course. But at the moment only one of the tables gets filled (what is also right in a way, but it would be nice to connect both, so that the list of courses of a person gets updatet when this person gets added to the persons list of a course).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that `OrderColumn` is necessary for storing the order. If there is a table `PERSON_COURSE` then you are missing the `mappedBy` on the `responsibleFor`. Do you really want to order that list as well, because this was not described in your original posting?

Comment: That's right. I'll better ask a new question, making this point clear and describing what I've achieved so far.